# Switch/Case in Matlab to If/Else Python

Tags: python, matlab, if-statement, switch-statement

I am working on translating some code from Matlab into Python. Currently I am working on this:

```
switch SIGNATURES_TYPE
    case 1
        rand('seed',5);
        load('USGS_1995_Library')
        wavlen=datalib(:,1);    % Wavelengths in microns
        [L n_materiais]=size(datalib);
        # select randomly
        sel_mat = 4+randperm(n_materiais-4);
        sel_mat = sel_mat(1:p);
        M = datalib(:,sel_mat);
        # print selected endmembers
        clear datalib wavelen names aux st;
    case 2
        error('type not available')
    case 3
        M = rand(L,p);
    case 4
        M = randn(L,p);
    case 5
        L=p;
        M = diag(linspace(1,(1/(COND_NUMBER)^(1/DECAY)),p).^DECAY);
    case 6
        L=p;
        M = diag(linspace(1,(1/(COND_NUMBER)^(1/DECAY)),p).^DECAY);
        A = randn(p);
        [U,D,V] = svd(A);
        M = U*M*V';
        clear A U D V;
    otherwise
        error('wrong signatute type')
end
```

Previously I had worked on a similar Switch/Case code:

```
for i=1:2:(length(varargin)-1)
    switch upper(varargin{i})
        case 'MM_ITERS'
            MMiters = varargin{i+1};
        case 'SPHERIZE'
            spherize = varargin{i+1};
```

The latter I was able to translate to this:

```
for i in range(1, 2, length(*args)-1):
        if (arg[i].upper() == "MM_ITERS"):
            MMiters = arg(i+1)
        elif (arg[i].upper() == "SPHERIZE"):
            spherize = arg(i+1)
```

However for the former I am wondering how I can create similar if statements. For example, for the first case can my code be something like:

```
if SIGNATURES_TYPE == 0:
    ** finish function
```

I wanted to know if something like this works or if it would be better to perhaps separate out statements into separate functions and then call them?

Thanks for the help and input!

Comment: The direct translation is just `if SIGNATURES_TYPE == 1:`, `elif SIGNATURES_TYPE == 2:`, etc. Is there a reason that's not good enough?

Comment: You can also use a dictionary to kinda emulate switch case functionality, if you don't like if/elif/else

Comment: No, my intuition was that the direct translation was just like that, but for some reason it slipped my mind that that should be how I code it. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if`/`else` construct would work.  Another way to do this is to use a `dict` where the keys are the signature types and the values are functions that return `M`.  This has the advantage of not having to clear anything.  So it would look something like this:

```
def case1(p):
    # calculate L and M
    return L, M

def case6(p):
    # calculate M
    return p, M

try:
    L, M = {1: case1(p),
            3: (L, np.random.rand(L, p)),
            4: (L, np.random.randn(L,p)),
            5: (p, np.diag(np.linspace(1,(1/(COND_NUMBER)**(1/DECAY)),p)**DECAY),
            6: case6(p)}[SIGNATURES_TYPE]
except KeyError:
    raise ValueError('Wrong signatute type: {}'.format(SIGNATURES_TYPE))
```

As for your previous example, the MATLAB code is a workaround for the lack of default argument handling.  Python has default argument handling, so you don't need the `if`/`else` or loop at all.  You can just do something like:

```
def myfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3, MM_ITERS=MM_ITERS_default, SPHERIZE=SPHERIZE_default):
```

where `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3` are the required arguments (the number doesn't matter, there could even be zero).  `MM_ITERS_default` and `SPHERIZE_default` are the values you want the corresponding variables to hold when the user doesn't define them.  You can even collect the arguments directly into a dict, using:

```
def myfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3, **kwargs):
```

Then you can access, say `MM_ITERS`, just using something like:

```
if MM_ITERS in kwargs:
    MM_ITERS = kwargs[MM_ITERS]`
```

Or

```
MM_ITERS = kwargs.get(MM_ITERS, MM_ITERS_default)
```

But generally it is easier to just use the default argument handling I showed earlier.

Comment: Thank you for help! This was very clear. I am new to both Matlab and Python and could not understand the need to use command line arguments in the Matlab code. Just to clarify, If I were to set the default value of a variable in the function definition, when the method is actually called with a different value, that value will be used by the method?

Comment: @A.Torres: Yes.  So say you call `myfunc(val1, val2, val3)`, then the `MM_ITERS` variable would have `MM_ITERS_default` and `SPHERIZE` would have `SPHERIZE_default`.  On the other hand if you called `myfunc(val1, val2, val3, val4)`, then `MM_ITERS` would have `val4` while `SPHERIZE` would have `SPHERIZE_default`.  And `myfunc(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5)`, has `val4` for `MM_ITERS` and `val5` for `SPHERIZE`.  You could also do, for example, `myfunc(val1, val2, val3, SPHERIZE=val5)`, in which case `MM_ITERS` variable would have `MM_ITERS_default` and `SPHERIZE` would have `val5`.